# Silverlight Financial Data

Tags: silverlight, web-services, onlinebanking

Does anyone know of any documentation of how to access bank data via some sort of webservice or other method for use in a Silverlight financial / banking application? Is there any sort of standard protocol or terminology used for this that I can look up online. I'm having trouble finding any sort of information on how this is typically done.

Comment: "Speak to the bank in question" is probably the best advice. I'm not aware of any that have a Silverlight app (closest would be Natwest in the UK with an iPad app). Bear in mind there are security implications in a bank supporting an API...

Answer (score 0):

"Access bank data"... Not exactly something banks allow from the outside world. They kinda want to keep things secure :)

*If* you work for a bank you may well have access to various web services *internally*. There are standards for data transfers, but every bank will likely have it's own systems.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble finding any sort of information on how this is typically done.

That's probably a good thing.  This is typically done by either internal bank developers or consultants.  For example, take the Bank of America Windows Phone 7 app (which is a Silverlight app): it connects to BofA's servers, but I would be surprised if the way in which it connects is public information.  Because you can use it to check your account, I can only presume that there is a web service hosted somewhere that allows these clients to get this data.  I'm pretty confident, however, that the connection is secured, and the details of it are kept hidden for good reason.

In short, banks don't usually expose web services to the outside world for public consumption.  Unless you've been hired by a bank to specifically do this, I'm not sure you **should** be able to.